# Organizing unit tests in angular app

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Testing modules dependent on other modules, and providers and services in them - possible. Let's say we need to test module 'A' that depends on module 'B':

*totally not coffeescript, rather pseudo code for brevity :)*

```
 beforeEach ->
    angular.module('B',[])
    module ($provide)->
       $provide.provider 'foo', -> 
           this.$get = ->  # ...etc...etc.

 it 'testing module A', ->
    module('A')     
    inject ->  # ...etc...etc.
```

Now, imagine we have quite a few modules that need to be mocked, and many services and providers. So how would you move faking 'B' part into a separate file? 
and how they'd be used after? It's quite possible to use module loaders (webpack, browserify) but how would one do without? Using angular capabilities and what Karma offers out of the box?

Is it possible to wrap entire mock into an angular module and load it in `beforeEach`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually, making services their own modules can easily be tested in Angular using Karma.

As long as you have your testing framework set up properly—Angular mocks, and all of the required modules are loaded into Karma (check the Karma config)—then this is fairly straight-forward.

The below example assumes `FirstService` is the service you are testing, and `SecondService` is another service that FirstService depends on and interacts with.

```
describe('FirstService', function () {
  var SecondService;

  beforeEach(module('FirstService'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_SecondService_) {
    SecondService = _SecondService_;
    spyOn(SecondService, 'doSomethingElse');
  }));

  it('calls SecondService.doSomethingElse', function () {
    FirstService.doSomething();

    expect(SecondService.doSomethingElse).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You include the module in a `beforeEach` as specified on the first line—do not use square brackets `[]` when including it as that redefines the module and you want to include the existing module as-is.

Although you should omit the square brackets when importing modules, you should be sure that when you are initially creating your FirstService module (e.g., in your `app.js` file, if that's how your project is set up) that you are indeed including SecondService as a dependency:

```
angular.module('FirstService', ['SecondService'])
```

The second `beforeEach` is injecting the SecondService module. It is already globally available to be injected and can be accessed by its module name with a leading and trailing underscore, i.e. `_SecondService_`. I've assigned it to a variable so that it is available to be used in the `it` statements, otherwise I would need to inject it in each `it` statement instead of a `beforeEach`.

I am creating a spy using Jasmine's `spyOn` to spy on the method `doSomethingElse` to ensure it has been called. The second parameter of `spyOn` (the method name) should have quotes but the first should not—it should be the variable you just defined for your SecondService.

The example unit test tests that calling `FirstService.doSomething()` calls `SecondService.doSomethingElse()`.

Comment: I still don't get it... let's say I am testing a module that depends on `ui.router` module. I need to mock ui.router's $stateProvider. I can do it in the same spec file for my SUT (module I'm testing). But what if the same logic (mock of $stateProvider) needs to be used in other specs as well. Then I need to put it in a separate file.
I can't just do something like ` angular.module('ui.router', []); module(function($provide) { ... etc` - that didn't work. I can wrap the mocking logic in other module, say named 'mocks' and then using angular.injector load that module, that's a russian doll hack

Comment: If you are trying to access the current state, you can inject `$state`.

    describe('FirstService', function () {
      var $state;

      beforeEach(module('FirstService'));

      beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_) {
        $state = _$state_;
      }));

      it('calls SecondService.doSomethingElse', function () {
        FirstService.doSomething();

        expect($state.current.name).toBe('login');
      });
    });

What are you trying to access from the `$stateProvider`?

Comment: The code for my previous comment about injecting `$state`: `beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_) {$state = _$state_; }));` and check the current state like so: `expect($state.current.name).toBe('login');`